# $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^ 9} \, dx$

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^9} \, dx$

I tried taking the integral of $\Gamma_R = [0,R] \cup \gamma_R \cup I_R$, where we see that \gamma_R is the circle parametrized by $z = Re^{it}$ with $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. And $I_R$ is the line form $iR$ to $0$

one can note the following three things:

1) $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^ 9}\,dz$ = $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+z^ 9}\,dz$. (Note that $z$ is on the $x$-axis)

2) $\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{1}{1+z^ 9} = 0$. (By the ML inequality)

the main problem is when i parametrize $I^{-}_{R}$ with $z(x) = xi$ and $x \in [0,R]$. The main problem is that i get that:

3) $\int_{I_R}\frac{1}{1+z^9} = -\int_{I_R^-}\frac{1}{1+z^9} = -\int_{0}^{R} \frac{i}{ix^9 + 1}$.

note that i want to work towards taking $R$ to infinity eventually and then equal the sum of the integrals to the sum of the residuals of $\Gamma_R$ times $2\pi i$. The main problem here is that my term in 3), does not look like the form $c \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^ 9}$ with c a constant value. If i can get this done i think i'm finished.

PS: The singular points i got where $e^{\frac{\pi i}{9}},e^{\frac{3 \pi i}{9}}$.

Comment: Im just curious why you can't solve the integral using regular methods ( complex analysis I haven't learnt yet, but am curious)?

Comment: @LearningMath This is actually a pretty horrible problem to do with partial fractions. In fact, the method I know still uses complex numbers, just in a different fashion (to get a factorization of $x^9+1$).

Comment: Check [Type 5](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/372/coursenotes/Trapper_MethodsContourIntegrals.pdf)

Comment: @LearningMath i am trying to learn contourintegration in the complexplane, so i can eventually solve more difficult problems. On top of that using partial fractions is horrible as ian already stated :P

Comment: You actually used the wrong contour. You want to use a sector of angle $2\pi/9$. When you do that you don't get the $i$ in the denominator, because $\left ( e^{2 \pi i/9} \right )^9 = 1$.

Comment: i thought it was quite nice to choose it this way because I_r looks so nice. Because if i choose another sector i get an ugly term $xe^{\frac{2\pi i}{9}}$

Comment: Ians choice of angle with $2 \pi / k$ will work for any integrand on the form $\frac{1}{x^k+a}$

Comment: In general, for $k\in(0,~n)$ we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}~dx~=~\frac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg).$

Comment: @KeesTil The $dz$ that you get is still just $c dx$, and the function is otherwise the same as what you had.

Comment: yes i noted that, i get as answer $\frac{2\pi i }{9e^{8\pi i / 9}(1-e^{2\pi i /9})}$. Don't yet see how to turn that in a sinus...

Comment: $\frac{i}{e^{8 \pi i/9}} = e^{-i \pi i/9}$. Now multiply and recall the exponential form of sine.

Comment: i think i made a mistake in the first place, because 1 is also a singular point so i should include that too....

Comment: @KeesTil $1$ is not a singular point, you get $\frac{1}{2}$ there. There is only one singular point in the sector, namely $e^{\pi i/9}$.

Comment: o crap i made a mistake again thanks for that, i solved it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a simpler way, using Euler's $B$ function:

1) change the variable from $x$ to $y=x^9$. You'll get $\frac 1 9 \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {y^{- \frac 8 9}} {1+y} \mathbb{d}y$.

2) make a second change of variables: $t=\frac y {1+y}$; you'll get $\frac 1 9 \int \limits _0 ^1 t^{- \frac 8 9} (1-t)^ {- \frac 1 9} \mathbb{d}t$, which is $\frac 1 9 B(\frac 1 9, \frac 8 9)$.

3) finally, using that $B(x,y)=\frac {\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)} {\Gamma(x+y)}$ and $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(1-x) = \frac \pi {\sin( \pi x)}$, you'll get $\frac \pi {9 \sin \frac \pi 9}$.

Comment: Having actually had to prove the properties of the Gamma function you've just used, I would not say that this is easier to do if you have to prove the properties from scratch.

Comment: @Ian Whoever is dealing with complex integration has usually messed up with gamma and beta functions. Chances are the OP has already worked these things. Very nice answer. +1

Comment: @Ian: Agreed. I just don't know what are the OP's prerequisites. Sometimes Euler's functions are taught in the real analysis course, which comes before the complex analysis one.

Comment: @Timbuc Maybe so. In my class the discussion of the Gamma function was very near the end and was in my view much more difficult than any of the residue calculus work, except perhaps for awkward problems like this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430218/dogbone-contour-integral-branch-cuts-residue-at-infinity But then, if you are used to things like the reflection formula, this is still a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Let's solve a harder problem...$$\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^p}} dx$$
Let $u=x^p$...
$$\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^p}} dx={1 \over p} \int_0^{\infty} {u^{{1 \over p}-1} \over {1+u}} du$$
The definition of the Beta function is...
$$B(p,q)=\int_0^{\infty} {{t^{n-1} \over ({t+1})^{p+q}} dt}$$
Note the striking similarity and evaluate accordingly...
$${1 \over p} \cdot B \left({1 \over p},1-{1 \over p} \right)$$ 
Use the Beta function's relation with the Gamma function to get...
$${1 \over p} \cdot B \left({1 \over p},1-{1 \over p} \right)={1 \over p} \cdot {{\Gamma \left({1 \over p} \right) \cdot \Gamma \left(1-{1 \over p} \right)} \over {\Gamma (1)}}$$

Use Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma (x) \cdot \Gamma (1-x)= \pi \csc(\pi x)$.
You should arrive at...
$$\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^p}} dx={\pi \over p} \cdot \csc \left( {\pi \over p }\right)$$
For $p=9$...
$$\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^9}} dx={\pi \over 9} \cdot \csc \left( {\pi \over 9} \right)=1.0206...$$

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to evaluate the general case is to consider a sector surrounding one residue, rather than a whole circle because it's easier to compute the contour integral. To start, consider the function

$$f(z)=\frac 1{z^n+1}$$

Where $n$ is an integer. Now imagine a "pizza slice" contour of radius $R$ pictured below

[image: C]

As $R\to\infty$, the arc integral vanishes. Leaving us with

$$\oint\limits_{C}dz\, f(z)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, f(x)-e^{2\pi i/n}\int\limits_0^{\infty}dz\, f(z)$$

Here, observe that if you take out a factor of $e^{\pi i/n}$, you get$$e^{\pi i/n}(e^{-\pi i/n}-e^{\pi i/n})\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, f(x)=-2i e^{\pi i/n}\sin\left(\frac {\pi}n\right)\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, f(x)$$The contour integral as only one residue at $z=e^{\pi i/n}$. The residue is given by

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{\pi i/n}}\frac 1{1+z^n}=\lim\limits_{z\to e^{\pi i/n}}\frac {z-e^{\pi i/n}}{z^n+1}=-\frac 1ne^{\pi i/n}$$Therefore$$-2ie^{\pi i/n}\sin\left(\frac {\pi}n\right)\int\limits_0^{\infty}dx\, f(x)=-\frac {2\pi i}ne^{\pi i/n}$$

Simplify both sides you see that

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac {dx}{1+x^n}=\frac {\pi}n\csc\left(\frac {\pi}n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this using contour analysis by judiciously selecting our closed contour.  We know that there are poles at $e^{i(2n-1)\pi/9}$ for $n=1,\dots,9$.

To that end, we let $C$ be the closed contour comprised of $(1)$ the straight line segment from $0$ to $R$, $(2)$ the circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{i2\pi/9}$, and $(3)$ the straight line segment from $Re^{i2\pi/9}$ to $0$.

---

> Note that for $R>1$, $C$ encloses only the pole at $z=e^{i\pi/9}$ and that on the straight line segment from $Re^{i2\pi/9}$ to $0$, $z^9=(te^{i2\pi/9})^9=t^9$, for $t\in [0,R]$.

---

Applying the residue theorem for any $R>1$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C\frac{1}{1+z^9}\,dz &=\int_0^R \frac{1}{1+x^9}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi/9}\frac{1}{1+R^9e^{i9\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_R^0 \frac{1}{1+(xe^{i2\pi/9})^9}\,e^{i2\pi/9}\,dx\\\\
&=(1-e^{i2\pi/9})\int_0^R \frac{1}{1+x^9}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi/9}\frac{1}{1+R^9e^{i9\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac1{1+z^9},z=e^{i\pi/9}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \lim_{z\to e^{i\pi/9}}\left(\frac{z-e^{i\pi/9}}{1+z^9}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{1}{9e^{i8\pi/9}}\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Letting $R\to \infty$, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^9}\,dx=\frac{2\pi i }{9}\frac{1}{e^{i8\pi/9(1-e^{i2\pi/9})}}=\frac{\pi}{9\sin(\pi/9)}$$

as expected!